# Passing string array in retrofit gives \" in every string in response

Tags: android, retrofit

I am sending string array with images using multipart in retrofit. It sends strings data with "".

```
HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(Constants.Params.USER_ID, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), activity.preferenceHelper.getUserDetail().getId()));
            map.put(Constants.Params.SERVER_TOKEN, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), activity.preferenceHelper.getUserDetail().getServerToken()));
            if (address != null) {
                map.put(Constants.Params.LATITUDE, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), address.getLatitude()));
                map.put(Constants.Params.LONGITUDE, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), address.getLongitude()));
                map.put(Constants.Params.ADDRESS, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), address.getAddress()));
                map.put(Constants.Params.ADDRESS_NOTE, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), ""));
                if (activity.preferenceHelper.getUserDetail() != null) {
                    map.put(Constants.Params.COUNTRY_ID, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), activity.preferenceHelper.getUserDetail().getCountryId()));
                }
            }
            Service service = activity.placeRequestData.getService();
            if (service != null) {
                map.put(Constants.Params.SERVICE_ID, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), service.getId()));
            }

            map.put(Constants.Params.PAYMENT_MODE, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), String.valueOf(activity.placeRequestData.getPaymentMode())));
            map.put(Constants.Params.DESCRIPTION, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), activity.placeRequestData.getDescription()));
            map.put(Constants.Params.REQUEST_TYPE, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), "1"));
            map.put(Constants.Params.REQUEST_TIME, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), activity.placeRequestData.getSelectedDateTime()));
            map.put(Constants.Params.TIMEZONE, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Constants.TEXT), String.valueOf(TimeZone.getDefault().getID())));

            **SubServiceType subServiceType;
            ArrayList<String> subServiceArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < subServiceTypes.size(); i++) {
                subServiceType = subServiceTypes.get(i);
                if (subServiceType.isChecked()) {
                    subServiceArray.add(subServiceType.getName());
                }
            }**

            MultipartBody.Part parts[] = new MultipartBody.Part[3];
            ArrayList<String> images = activity.placeRequestData.getImages();
            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                parts[i] = Utilities.getMultiPartBody(images.get(i));
            }

            Call<ResponseCreateRequest> createRequestCall = activity.apiInterface.createRequest(map,
                    parts, subServiceArray);


@Multipart
    @POST("create/request")
    Call<ResponseCreateRequest> createRequest(@PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> hashMap,
                                              @Part MultipartBody.Part[] img1,
                                              @Part(Constants.Params.SUB_SERVICE_LIST) ArrayList<String> strings);
```

I am facing issue in **"SubServiceType"**.The response of this request is like :

```
{
    "sub_service_list":[
    "\"sasa\"",
    "\"dsds\"",
    "\"sdsdsd\""
    ]
 }
```

Check **"sub_service_list"** array in response it have \". how to send this string array so i can get proper format of string (without \")

Comment: its not android retrofit issue, try same api with postman , and check  the response

Comment: The \ is to escape the quotes (") that are part of the response.

Use stripslashes() to strip these out.

When a string wrapped in quotes contains quotes, they have to be escaped. The escape character in php is \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `ArrayList<String>` with `ArrayList<RequestBody>`

use this method to convert `String` to `RequestBody`

```
public static RequestBody createFromString(String string) {
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text"), string);
        return requestBody;
    }
```

**for example:**

```
 ArrayList<RequestBody> subServiceArray=new ArrayList<>()
 subServiceArray.add(createFromString(subServiceType.getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem some day before when i was trying to send a image and some fields in multipart. You need to have an `ArrayList<RequestBody>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`. then put each value with `MediaType TEXT` into the arraylist. That might solve your problem.

I hope this will help you. :)